# JPos scanner detected but not receiving data from it

Tags: java, barcode-scanner, javapos

I've been trying to get JPos to run with my customer's USB hand-scanner. It detects the scanner just fine apparently, but nothing pops up when they use it to read the cards. I've been using the library's sample source code just to make sure I can work with the device before implementing it into my main software. Here's the code that is supposed to test it (javafx fxml controller implementing jpos interface):

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import jpos.JposException;
import jpos.events.DataEvent;
import jpos.events.DataListener;

public class UI_Controller implements DataListener{

private jpos.Scanner scanner = new jpos.Scanner();
private jpos.Scanner scanner2 = new jpos.Scanner();

@FXML
TextArea textbox;

@FXML
TextArea textbox2;

@FXML
public void buttonClick() {
        updateBox(textbox, "Initialising JavaPOS...\n");
        // Create scanner instance and register for data events.
        scanner = new jpos.Scanner();

        // Initialize the scanner.  Exception thrown if a method fails.
        try {
            updateBox(textbox, "Adding DataListener...\n");
            scanner.addDataListener(this);
            updateBox(textbox, "Opening the device DLS-QW2120-USB-OEM...\n");
            scanner.open("DLS-QW2120-USB-OEM");
            updateBox(textbox, "Claiming the device...\n");
            scanner.claim(1000);
            updateBox(textbox, "Enabling the device...\n");
            scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
            updateBox(textbox, "Setting 'DataEventEnabled' property...\n");
            scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);
            updateBox(textbox, "---SUCCESS!---\n");
            updateBox(textbox, "[ LISTENING MODE ]");
        } catch (JposException ex) {
            updateBox(textbox, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[1] ===: \n" + ex.toString());
            updateBox(textbox, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");
            updateBox(textbox, "\nClosing DLS-QW2120-USB-OEM\n");
            try {
                scanner.close();
            } catch (JposException e) {
                updateBox(textbox, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[1] ===: \n" + e.toString());
                updateBox(textbox, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");
            }
            updateBox(textbox, "\nTrying DLS-QW2100-USB-OEM\n");
             try {
                updateBox(textbox, "Opening the device...\n");
                scanner.open("DLS-QW2100-USB-OEM");
                updateBox(textbox, "Claiming the device...\n");
                scanner.claim(1000);
                updateBox(textbox, "Adding DataListener...\n");
                scanner.addDataListener(this);
                updateBox(textbox, "Enabling the device...\n");
                scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
                updateBox(textbox, "Setting 'DataEventEnabled' property...\n");
                scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);
                updateBox(textbox, "---SUCCESS!---\n");
                updateBox(textbox, "[ LISTENING MODE ]");
            } catch (JposException ex2) {
                updateBox(textbox, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[1] ===: \n" + ex2.toString());
                updateBox(textbox, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");

            }
        }
        //...Success! Continue doing work...
}

@FXML
public void button2Click() {
    updateBox(textbox, "Initialising JavaPOS...\n");
    // Create scanner instance and register for data events.
    scanner2 = new jpos.Scanner();

    // Initialize the scanner.  Exception thrown if a method fails.
    try {
        scanner.close();
    } catch (JposException e) {
        updateBox(textbox, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[1] ===: \n" + e.toString());
        updateBox(textbox, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");
    }
    updateBox(textbox, "\nTrying DLS-QW2100-USB-OEM\n");
    updateBox(textbox, "Adding DataListener...\n");
    scanner2.addDataListener(this);
     try {
        updateBox(textbox, "Opening the device...\n");
        scanner2.open("DLS-QW2100-USB-OEM");
        updateBox(textbox, "Claiming the device...\n");
        scanner2.claim(1000);
        updateBox(textbox, "Enabling the device...\n");
        scanner2.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        updateBox(textbox, "Setting 'DataEventEnabled' property...\n");
        scanner2.setDataEventEnabled(true);
        updateBox(textbox, "---SUCCESS!---\n");
        updateBox(textbox, "[ LISTENING MODE ]");
    } catch (JposException ex2) {
        updateBox(textbox, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[1] ===: \n" + ex2.toString());
        updateBox(textbox, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");

    }
    //...Success! Continue doing work...

}


@Override
public void dataOccurred(DataEvent e) {
    jpos.Scanner sc = (jpos.Scanner) e.getSource();
    try {
        updateBox(textbox2, "[" + e.getStatus() + "] " + scanner.getScanData().toString() + "\n");
        sc.setDataEventEnabled(true);
    } catch (JposException ex){
        updateBox(textbox2, "=== JPOS EXCEPTION TRACE[2] ===: \n" + ex.toString());
        updateBox(textbox2, "\n=== END OF EXCEPTION ===\n");
    }

}
```

I skipped the updateBox() method as it only updates a particular textbox and prints out to stdout simultaneously.

A couple of notes:

- I'm testing for both QW2100 and QW2120 scanners as the first one is
  the one that was initially in the .xml driver, but the 2nd is the one
  my customer has and it's a record I added in the file manually.
- I'm pretty sure buttonClick() methods are working fine as we had issues even connecting to the device before (lacked .dlls) but now
  the customer says the scanner seems to connect, it's just the scanned
  numbers don't appear when the card is scanned
- I'd rather prepare an example with as many solutions as possible at once as I don't have the scanner myself and have to rely on the
  customer to run the testing app for me
- Textbox2 updates just fine, I've checked already and it's not an issue with updateBox() code

Here's a screenshot I received (it's from an older version before i introduced button2Click but both behave the same way): [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uektt.png)
It must be how I'm trying to receive the data (the scanner works fine with another software they're using at the moment), but looking through the docs etc. I have no clue what can be wrong as I'm trying to do the bare minimum.

XML records for completeness (2120 is the one I added):

```
 <JposEntry logicalName="DLS-QW2100-USB-OEM">
        <creation factoryClass="com.dls.jpos.service.DLSScannerInstanceFactory" serviceClass="com.dls.jpos.service.DLSScannerService"/>
        <vendor name="DLA" url="http://www.adc.datalogic.com"/>
        <jpos category="Scanner" version="1.13"/>
        <product description="ScannerService" name="ScannerService" url="http://www.adc.datalogic.com"/>
        <!--Other non JavaPOS required property (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
        <prop name="beepDuration" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="beepFrequency" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="beepVolume" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="canAcceptStatisticsCmd" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canCompareFirmwareVersion" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canNotifyPowerChange" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canUpdateFirmware" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="deviceBus" type="String" value="USB"/>
        <prop name="deviceClass" type="String" value="USBHHScanner"/>
        <prop name="deviceDescription" type="String" value="DLS QW2130 USB OEM Scanner"/>
        <prop name="deviceName" type="String" value="DLS QW2130 USB OEM Scanner"/>
        <prop name="doubleReadTimeout" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="enable2DigitSups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable4DigitPriceCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable5DigitPriceCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable5DigitSups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableBarCodeProgramming" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCodabar" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode128" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode128Sups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableCode39" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode39CheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableCode93" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableEANJAN2LabelDecode" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableGoodReadBeep" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableInterleaved" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableITFCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableLaserOnOffSwitch" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUCCEAN128" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCACheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCAtoEAN13Expansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCD1D5" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEAN" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCECheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEtoEAN13Expansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEtoUPCAExpansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableVolumeSwitch" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="fullDisable" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="itfLength1" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="itfLength2" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="itfRange" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="laserTimeout" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="ledGoodReadDuration" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="MBeansEnabled" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="motorTimeout" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="productId" type="String" value="1213"/>
        <prop name="scanControl" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="storeLabelSecurityLevel" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="twoItfs" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="usage" type="String" value="4B00"/>
        <prop name="vendorId" type="String" value="05F9"/>
        <prop name="WMIEnabled" type="String" value="False"/>
    </JposEntry>
    <JposEntry logicalName="DLS-QW2120-USB-OEM">
        <creation factoryClass="com.dls.jpos.service.DLSScannerInstanceFactory" serviceClass="com.dls.jpos.service.DLSScannerService"/>
        <vendor name="DLA" url="http://www.adc.datalogic.com"/>
        <jpos category="Scanner" version="1.13"/>
        <product description="ScannerService" name="ScannerService" url="http://www.adc.datalogic.com"/>
        <!--Other non JavaPOS required property (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
        <prop name="beepDuration" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="beepFrequency" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="beepVolume" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="canAcceptStatisticsCmd" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canCompareFirmwareVersion" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canNotifyPowerChange" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="canUpdateFirmware" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="deviceBus" type="String" value="USB"/>
        <prop name="deviceClass" type="String" value="USBHHScanner"/>
        <prop name="deviceDescription" type="String" value="DLS QW2130 USB OEM Scanner"/>
        <prop name="deviceName" type="String" value="DLS QW2130 USB OEM Scanner"/>
        <prop name="doubleReadTimeout" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="enable2DigitSups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable4DigitPriceCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable5DigitPriceCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enable5DigitSups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableBarCodeProgramming" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCodabar" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode128" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode128Sups" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableCode39" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableCode39CheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableCode93" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableEANJAN2LabelDecode" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableGoodReadBeep" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableInterleaved" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableITFCheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableLaserOnOffSwitch" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUCCEAN128" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCACheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCAtoEAN13Expansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCD1D5" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEAN" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCECheckDigit" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEtoEAN13Expansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableUPCEtoUPCAExpansion" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="enableVolumeSwitch" type="String" value="True"/>
        <prop name="fullDisable" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="itfLength1" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="itfLength2" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="itfRange" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="laserTimeout" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="ledGoodReadDuration" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="MBeansEnabled" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="motorTimeout" type="String" value="1"/>
        <prop name="productId" type="String" value="1213"/>
        <prop name="scanControl" type="String" value="False"/>
        <prop name="storeLabelSecurityLevel" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="twoItfs" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="usage" type="String" value="4B00"/>
        <prop name="vendorId" type="String" value="05F9"/>
        <prop name="WMIEnabled" type="String" value="False"/>
    </JposEntry>
```

Thank you.